# Spring boot + ActiveMQ + stomp broker relay failed to connect

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

I am following the this guide http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/ and but instead of using the simple message broker, I am trying to use the stomp broker relay

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic").setRelayHost("stomp://localhost").setRelayPort(61612);
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}
```

and I am trying but my console keeps showing failed to connect

> 2016-02-26 01:38:05.786  INFO 3584 --- [           main] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : Connecting "system" session to stomp://localhost:61612
>
> 2016-02-26 01:38:05.942  INFO 3584 --- [eactor-tcp-io-1] r.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient   : Failed to connect to stomp://localhost:61612. Attempting reconnect in 5000ms.
>
> 2016-02-26 01:38:05.957  INFO 3584 --- [           main] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : Started.
>
> 2016-02-26 01:38:06.025  INFO 3584 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8052 (http)
>
> 2016-02-26 01:38:06.025  INFO 3584 --- [           main] main.java.test.TestApplication             : Started TestApplication in 9.419 seconds (JVM running for 15.121)
>
> 2016-02-26 01:38:11.022  INFO 3584 --- [eactor-tcp-io-2] r.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient   : Failed to connect to stomp://localhost:61612. Attempting reconnect in 5000ms.
>
> 2016-02-26 01:38:16.008  INFO 3584 --- [eactor-tcp-io-3] r.io.net.impl.netty.tcp.NettyTcpClient   : Failed to connect to stomp://localhost:61612. Attempting reconnect in 5000ms.

My activemq.xml is the default except for this:

```
<transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://localhost:61612"/>
 </transportConnectors>
```

ActiveMQ starts up with no problems as I am able to connect to the admin page at http://localhost:8161/admin.

Here is my maven pom.xml in case someone spots out that I might be using the wrong dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.test.program</groupId>
<artifactId>testapp</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-net</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.34.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.34.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

</repositories>


<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Did you check if the stomp transport connector is up and running , activemq admin page might be accessible , check for the transport connectors

Comment: is there a special way to check ? as far as i know it does not show any address binding error in the console when i start up activemq.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I just needed to remove the "stomp://" prefix. As the spring configuration method implies it is a stomp relay, I did not need to add the prefix myself. Also need to enter a username and password if it is set in the default activemq installation.

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic")
        .setRelayHost("127.0.0.1")
        .setRelayPort(61613)
        .setClientLogin("system")
        .setClientPasscode("password")
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the configureMessageBroker as shown below

```
 @Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic").setRelayHost("localhost").setRelayPort(15672).setClientLogin("guest")
            .setClientPasscode("guest");
}
```